# Extract primary SMTP address from exchange account using Redemption in Outlook

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, outlook-redemption

Is there a way to get the primary SMTP address from an exchange account in Outlook ? I am currently using Redemption and following code keeps returning an empty value.

```
> IRDOExchangeAccount exAcc = (IRDOExchangeAccount)rdoAcc;              
> string email = exchangeAccount.CurrentUser.SMTPAddress;
```

Currently I am using

> exchangeAccount.CurrentUser.Address

property to get the Email and seems it gets me the correct Email address. How reliable that property is ? Is there another better way ?

Comment: What do you see in OutlookSpy if you click IMAPISession | QueryIdentity?

Comment: Gets the list of Pst s available with properties such as Display name, entry id (with property tags)...etc . However, clicking QueryIdentity, crashes outlook :(

Comment: "Crashed" as in produces an access violation in Outlook? Can you send an email to Redemption support at http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/contact.htm? I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: I  already have the debug version. Ill drop you the debug log when possible